# setOnKeyPressed event not working properly

Tags: java, javafx-2, keylistener

I am in need to create a generated tunnel-like thing with curves for my project in the university. I found some code in the Internet that allowed me to drag the controlpoint (attached to Anchor object) of the curve.

However, I wanted to make it possible to change the controlpoint Ylocation by pressing arrow keys ("up" and "down") and somehow it's not working at all. I have been trying to hopelessly solve this issue myself, but I can' t find the way out.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/** Example of how a cubic curve works, drag the anchors around to change the curve. */
public class testsdfasdf extends Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { launch(args); }


  @Override public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    QuadCurve curve = createStartingCurve();


    final BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1000, 1000);

    final Anchor control2 = new Anchor(Color.GOLDENROD, curve.controlXProperty(), curve.controlYProperty());


    root.getChildren().add(curve);
    root.getChildren().add(control2);


    primaryStage.setTitle("Quadcurve Manipulation");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
  }

  private QuadCurve createStartingCurve() {
    QuadCurve curve = new QuadCurve();
    curve.setStartX(100);
    curve.setStartY(100);
    curve.setControlX(200);
    curve.setControlY(50);
    curve.setEndX(300);
    curve.setEndY(100);
    curve.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
    curve.setStrokeWidth(10);
    curve.setStrokeLineCap(StrokeLineCap.ROUND);
    curve.setFill(Color.CORNSILK.deriveColor(0, 1.2, 1, 0.6));
    return curve;
  }

  // a draggable anchor displayed around a point.
  class Anchor extends Circle { 

      Anchor(Color color, DoubleProperty x, DoubleProperty y) {
      super(x.get(), y.get(), 10);
      setFill(color.deriveColor(1, 1, 1, 0.5));

      y.bind(centerYProperty());
      enableDrag();
      changeCurve();
    }


    private void changeCurve() {
        setOnKeyPressed((event) -> { 
                System.out.println(event.getCode() == KeyCode.DOWN);
                if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.DOWN) {
                    double newY = getCenterY();
                    while (newY > 0 && newY < getScene().getHeight()) {
                        setCenterY(newY);
                        newY+=1;
                    }
                }
                else if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.UP) {
                    double newY = getCenterY();
                    while (newY > 0 && newY < getScene().getHeight()) {
                        setCenterY(newY);
                        newY-=1;
                    }
                }
        });
        setOnKeyReleased((event) -> {
                if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.DOWN) {
                }
                if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.UP) {
                }

            });
    }

    // make a node movable by dragging it around with the mouse.
    private void enableDrag() {
      setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
          // record a delta distance for the drag and drop operation.
          getScene().setCursor(Cursor.MOVE);
        }
      });
      setOnMouseReleased(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
          getScene().setCursor(Cursor.HAND);
        }
      });
      setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
          double newY = mouseEvent.getY();
          System.out.println(newY);
          if (newY > 0 && newY < getScene().getHeight()) {
            setCenterY(newY);
          }  
        }
      });
      setOnMouseEntered(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
          if (!mouseEvent.isPrimaryButtonDown()) {
            getScene().setCursor(Cursor.HAND);
          }
        }
      });
      setOnMouseExited(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
          if (!mouseEvent.isPrimaryButtonDown()) {
            getScene().setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
          }
        }
      });
    }
  }  
}
```

Maybe there' s too much code here. But that is all to actually draw the curve there and make it draggable with **enableDrag()** function.

**changeCurve()** function is not working and that' s the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Problem**

A node will not listen to events unless they are focused. Your cirle never receives focus and therefore, never reacts to the Key Events.

**Solution**

One of the *easy* solutions would be to ask for focus after the stage is displayed.

```
primaryStage.show();
control2.requestFocus();
```

Another solution would be to bind the Scene's `onKeyPressedProperty` to the Circle's `onKeyPressedProperty`. This will bind all the key press events taking place on the Scene to the Circle.

*There might be situations where you would not want to do this..*

```
scene.onKeyPressedProperty().bind(control2.onKeyPressedProperty());
```

There is also a small issue with your `handle()` as well. There is no need of the `while loop`. You just want to `setCenterY()` to a value less/more than the previous value, depending on the key pressed.

```
setOnKeyPressed((event) -> {
     if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.DOWN && getCenterY() < getScene().getHeight()){
         setCenterY(getCenterY() + 5);
     } else if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.UP && getCenterY() > 0) {
         setCenterY(getCenterY() - 5);
     }
});
```

Comment: Thanks alot. As I am in hurry to finish this project I had to google harder until I found similar ways that you provided me to move my circle. Maybe it's abit off-topic, but I want to know more about curves. Is it possible to somehow remove the box around the Curve object so I could use it in my game for collision?

Comment: Thanks so much, it worked for me!!! I was creating a Menu for a game, where I need to use key events from the scene and then blind them to be able to use the key event from another class.