# RIGHT and LEFT keys cause selection in borderPane in javafx

Tags: java, javafx, keyboard, slider

This is the situation:

The main root is a `BorderPane` called wrapper which has an `HBox` as `top` and another as it's `bottom` and this bottom `HBox` has a `Slider` and a `CheckBox` in it. And there is also a `Pane` called `game` as it's `center` where the game runs.

Now I have these `RIGHT` and `LEFT` keyboard keys used in the game but when I run the game the `Slider` is automatically selected and when I press the keys the `Slider` goes to right and left and the game doesn't realize the buttons are pressed.

Here is my code for taking the keys:

```
wrapper.setOnKeyPressed(ke -> {            
    int angle = 0;
    Rotate orangeCircleRotation = new Rotate(0, CIRCLES_CENTER_X, CIRCLES_CENTER_Y);
    orangeCircle.getTransforms().add(orangeCircleRotation);
    Rotate yellowCircleRotation = new Rotate(0, CIRCLES_CENTER_X, CIRCLES_CENTER_Y);
    yellowCircle.getTransforms().add(yellowCircleRotation);
    Timeline rotationAnimation = new Timeline();
    if (ke.getCode().toString().equals("RIGHT")) {
        angle = -36;
    }
    if (ke.getCode().toString().equals("Left")) {
        angle = 36;
    }
    rotationAnimation.getKeyFrames().add(
                    new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(100),
                            new KeyValue(orangeCircleRotation.angleProperty(), angle)));
    rotationAnimation.getKeyFrames().add(
                    new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(100),
                            new KeyValue(yellowCircleRotation.angleProperty(), angle)));
    rotationAnimation.play();
}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32802664/setonkeypressed-event-not-working-properly. Just your problem is that your slider gots focus, so you can call `.setFocusTraversable(false)` on it to prevent getting focused, but this does not solve that if gets focused "manually" (e.g. mouse) it will "eat" the event. In the linked answer also there is a solution for that: `scene.onKeyPressedProperty().bind(slider.onKeyPressedProperty());` - as long as that you move the listener from your `BorderPane` to your `Scene`, which you shall do :)

Comment: thank you very much .setFocusTraversable(false) worked for me:)

Comment: scene.onKeyPressedProperty().bind(slider.onKeyPressedProperty()); won't work for me bc then the slider will go to right and left all the time and the sound volume will change all the time while the player is playing.

Comment: i cant do "as long as that you move the listener from your BorderPane to your Scene, which you shall do :)" eaither bc i have a pause menu as popup and if i do this then while the game is paused the player can still move the circles in the game:)

Comment: Ah okay, I did not know your use case, that's why I just commented. I guess it would be ideal to disable every control during the gameplay and enable them only in paused state. From pause -> game, you can use `requestFocus()` on your borderpane. With this aproach you could have the keylistener on your scene => it ensures that in gameplay state every key event is handled.